# Character Variety; why is it a variety?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $\pi$ be a finitely generated group. Its character variety is defined as $$Ch(\pi) := \operatorname{Hom}(\pi ,\mathbb C^*) .$$

Why is this a variety? This can be generalised by replacing $\mathbb C^*$, but I think it would be helpful for me to understand this example first.

I noted, that $\operatorname{Hom}(\pi ,\mathbb C^*) = \operatorname{Hom}(\pi_{ab} ,\mathbb C^*) = (\mathbb C^*)^n \oplus T$, wtih $T$ the torsion part. But still, why is this a variety? 
First of all, is it an affine or projective variety, and what are the defining polynomials?

Comment: $Hom(G,\Gamma)$ is a subvariety of $\Gamma^r$, see [here](http://www.people.virginia.edu/~sm4cw/AMS_Conference_files/Lawton-AMS.pdf), where $r$ is the number of generators of $G$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Thank you, this is a nice overwiew about the subject. Do you know, where I can find something more detailled? Like a book?

Comment: https://bookstore.ams.org/memo-58-336/

Comment: $G$ is a group finitely generated by $g_1,\ldots,g_N \in G$, $Hom(G,\Bbb{C}^*) = Hom(G^{ab},\Bbb{C}^*)$ where $G^{ab} = G/[G,G]$ is a finitely generated abelian group, let $L = \{ e\in \Bbb{Z}^N, \prod_n g_n^{e_n} = 1  \in G^{ab} \}$ it is a lattice in $\Bbb{Z}^N$, with $L' = \Bbb{Q} L \cap \Bbb{Z}^N$ then $\Bbb{Z}^N = L' \oplus \Lambda$ and $(\Bbb{C}^*)^{N-\dim(L')}= Hom(\Lambda,\Bbb{C}^*)=Hom(\Bbb{Z}^N/L',\Bbb{C}^*) = Hom(G^{ab}/G^{ab}_{tors},\Bbb{C}^*)$, those characters are to be pointwise multiplied with the finitely many characters of $G^{ab}_{tors} = \Bbb{Z}^N / (\Lambda\oplus L)$.

Comment: Choose generators $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ and relations $r_i(x_1, \cdots, x_n)=0$ for $i=1, \cdots, k$. Then your character variety will be the subvariety of $\mathbb{G}_m^n$ given by the vanishing locus of your relations $r_1, \cdots, r_k$. Here $\mathbb{G}_m:=\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}[X,X^{-1}]$ is the multiplicative group over $\mathbb{C}$.