# Dimension of the space of irreducible rank $1$ representations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.00205.pdf) says that given a finitely generated group $\Gamma$, let $d_N(\Gamma)$ be the dimension of the space of irreducible rank $N$ representations. The number $d_1(\Gamma)$ coincides with the first Betti number, so one may think of $d_N(\Gamma)$ as a nonabelian generalisation.

Now given a compact manifold $X$, take $\Gamma$ to be $\pi_1(X)$, then the the space of irreducible rank $1$ representations is just the $Hom(\pi_1(X),\mathbb{C}^*)\cong Hom(H_1(X),\mathbb{C}^*)\cong H^1(X,\mathbb{C}^*)$. Now I wonder why $H^1(X,\mathbb{C}^*)$ is a vector space?

And $\mathbb{C}^*$ is not a ring, I wonder how to get the first Betti number?

Also what does it mean by "so one may think of $d_N(\Gamma)$ as a nonabelian generalisation"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why should this be a vector space? It is not. As for the statement in the paper: It is correct. The space $Hom_{irr}(\pi_1, GL(n, {\mathbb C}))$ (or a suitable quotient of this space by the action of $GL(n, {\mathbb C})$) is a complex-algebraic variety, so it has dimension. This dimension can be regarded as a generalization of the dimension of a vector space, just as the dimension of a general topological space is a far-reaching generalization of the notion of dimension from linear algebra.

Edit 1. In order to see that $Hom(\pi_1, GL(n, {\mathbb C}))$ is an algebraic variety, consider a presentation of $\pi_1$:
$$
<s_1,...,s_k| R_1(s_1,..,s_k), R_2(s_1,...,s_k),....>. 
$$
Then $Hom(\pi_1, GL(n, {\mathbb C}))$ is identified with the subset of $GL(n, {\mathbb C})^k$ given by the equations
$$
R_i(x_1,...,x_k)=1, i=1,2,...
$$ 
and inequalities $det(x_1)\ne 0,..., det(x_k)\ne 0$, 
where $(x_1,...,x_k)\in Mat(n\times n, {\mathbb C})^k$.

The latter is a complex-algebraic variety (not necessarily irreducible). 
One can verify that the subset of irreducible representations is Zariski-open, making $Hom_{irr}(\pi_1, GL(n, {\mathbb C}))$ an algebraic variety as well. Regarding quotients by conjugation, see the reference I gave [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3284915/character-variety-why-is-it-a-variety).

Edit 2. The subset of irreducible representations is Zariski-open is proven for instance in Proposition 1.10 (page 11) in the book

Alexander Lubotzky, Andy R. Magid, [Varieties of Representations of Finitely Generated Groups](https://bookstore.ams.org/memo-58-336/), Memoirs of AMS, vol. 336, 1985.

Make sure you read the discussion on the preceding page 10 as well.

Edit 3. In fact, $Hom(\pi, GL(n))$ is not just a variety but a scheme, this is again explained nicely in the reference above. The associated functor of points is
$$
A\mapsto Hom(\pi, GL(n))[A]= Hom(\pi, GL(n,A))
$$
for commutative rings $A$. This scheme has a quotient, traditionally called the **character scheme** (topologists tend to call the quotient the  *character variety*), which can be understood either as the GIT/Mumford quotient 
$$
X=X(\pi, n)=Hom(\pi, GL(n))//GL(n)
$$
where $GL(n)$ acting on representations via conjugation (see the same reference) or, better as a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(mathematics)). For the latter interpretation I do not have a good reference. This distinction becomes important for instance when you consider the Zariski tangent space of the character scheme at $[\rho]\in X=X(\pi,n)$: In general it is not isomorphic to $H^1(\pi, Ad\circ \rho)$. However, if one interprets  $X$ as a stack, then 
$$
T_{[\rho]} X\cong H^1(\pi, Ad\circ \rho). 
$$

Comment: This answer is not complete

Comment: @Danny: It is complete, what else would you want to know?

Comment: For example, my last question. For example, why is that a complex algebraic variety? For example, why is the dimension the first Betti number? For example...

Comment: @Danny: Your last question I answered; the dimension of $Hom_{irr}(\pi_1, GL(n, {\mathbb C}))$ has very little to do with any Betti numbers once $n\ge 2$. As for why it is an algebraic variety, I will add an explanation.

Comment: why is the dimension $Hom(\pi_1(X), GL(1,\mathbb{C})$ equal to the first Betti number of $X$?

Comment: @Danny: Are you familiar with the universal coefficient theorem for cohomology?

Comment: I know but $C^*$ is not s ring, how do you define the rank of $GL(1,C^*)$?

Comment: It is a complex manifold (actually, an abelian complex algebraic group), so you use its dimension as a complex manifold, it will equal the 1st Betti number.